# How to upload a file using AngularJs like the traditional way

Tags: file-upload, angularjs, carrierwave

I've been tried this for days. Assuming I have a form like following:

```
    <form ng-submit="create()" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">name : </label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" ng-model="message.title" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">avatar : </label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="file" ng-model="message.avatar" name="message[avatar]" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="well">
        <input class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit" value="建立資料" />
      </div>
    </form>
```

I am using the carrierwave gem to handle the file upload behind the scene. My controller is like this:

```
 $scope.create = function($scope.message){
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   $http({
       method: 'POST',
       url: '/resources/messages',
       data: $.param({message: message}),
       headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
   }).
     success(function(data, status, headers, config){
       deferred.resolve(data);
     }).
     error(function(data, status, headers, config){
       deferred.reject(status);
     });
   return deferred.promise;
  };
```

However it is not working. What I intend to do is create a form and upload everything like the old way, but the examples I found such as ng-upload, or like [this post](http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/a-directive-to-manage-file-upload-in-an-angularjs-application), or [jquery file upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/), they don't suit my need. Is there any example or sample code for this purpose? Thank you.

Comment: Here's a fiddle that handles doing some file upload in angular using xhr if this isn't what you're looking for could you provide more details on what you do want since what you've found isn't it: http://jsfiddle.net/danielzen/utp7j/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think "like the old way" would be to not use Ajax, but I'm guessing that's not what you mean. :)

@shaunhusain's fiddle is a good example of how to use the [FormData object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) to handle the file upload. And using [this site](http://badwing.com/multipart-form-data-ajax-uploads-with-angularjs/) as a reference, you can use the `transformRequest` to incorporate the FormData object.

Keeping your basic `$http` code, modify it to add the transform object:

```
$scope.create = function(message){
var deferred = $q.defer();
$http({
   method: 'POST',
   url: '/resources/messages',
   data: message // your original form data,
   transformRequest: formDataObject  // this sends your data to the formDataObject provider that we are defining below.
   headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
}).
 success(function(data, status, headers, config){
   deferred.resolve(data);
 }).
 error(function(data, status, headers, config){
   deferred.reject(status);
 });
return deferred.promise;
};
```

Create a factory that will incorporate manipulate the form data into a sendable payload. It will iterate through your form data (including uploaded file) and return a sender-friendly object:

```
app.factory('formDataObject', function() {
    return function(data) {
        var fd = new FormData();
        angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
            fd.append(key, value);
        });
        return fd;
    };
});
```

I haven't tested this, but it should work out of the box.

Comment: I had to set `Content-Type` to `undefined`. Otherwise the boundary wasn't getting set by the browser.

Comment: FormData isn't supported by IE9. Is there a way around this?