# FormidableJS form does not parse when posted from AngularJS

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, formidable

I am posting to a formidable form from AngularJS, but the form does not parse. I do not use the express.bodyParser(), which I understand often is a problem.

**serverside:**

```
...
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
console.log(form); //this prints
//Get access to the other fields of the request. 
form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
    console.log("parsing.."); //this does not print
    console.log(fields);
    console.log(files);`
...
```

**client-side:**

```
...
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/api/ad',
    data: message, // your original form data,
    transformRequest: formDataObject,  // this sends your data to the formDataObject provider that we are defining below. `[see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629126/how-to-upload-a-file-using-angularjs-like-the-traditional-way)`
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
                    })
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                        deferred.resolve(data); ` 
...
```

When posting form Angular with the formData object, I have to set the content/type to undefined as mentioned in the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629126/how-to-upload-a-file-using-angularjs-like-the-traditional-way). Might that be a problem for formidable?

I have been using hours to try to figure this out with no luck. I would be very grateful for any answers!

Answer (score 2):

I figured out this. I had to bind the files to the controller, as well as using the angular.identity function. Based on [this great explanation](http://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs) I added the following to my angular code in order to bind files to the controller: `

```
myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;`

            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

and the following to post my form to the url I wanted:

```
myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(data, uploadUrl){
        var fd = new FormData();
        angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
            fd.append(key, value);
        });
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function(retObj){
        console.log(retObj);
        })
        .error(function(retObj){
        console.log(retObj);
        });
    }
}]);
```

In the submit-function in the controller I now add:

```
var formData = $scope.newForm;
        var uploadUrl = '/api/add';
        fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(formData, uploadUrl);
```

and in my html, files-inputs gets the following tag in order to use the created file-model:

```
<input type="file" file-model="newForm.image1">
```

and my text inputs are just binded as before:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="newForm.title">
```

Hope this helps someone else :)